# What is a 'normal' time for water to completely drain out of a shower pan?

Tags: shower, drainage

I installed a new shower with slimline tray. Now when I am showering there is a fair build up of water in the tray.  Nothing major or overflowing, but not quite perfect.
As a gauge, when I stop the shower flow it takes about 11 seconds for the water to drain away completely.

Is this normal or I am being paranoid and installed a dud?

Comment: Hi, are you saying the plumbing is not draining as fast as before? or that the slope of the shower pan towards the drain is so flat that it is taking 11 seconds? please post a pic or link to the product that you installed.

Comment: We are the first time users of the new set up having bought a 1960's house and refurbishing it. I guess what I am saying is I'd like the tray to not have any water at all around my toes but rather drain away instantaniously. Maybe I am being a bit of a perfectionist!

Comment: If a pan is set up right and you have proper escape plumbing then it should be pretty instant.

Comment: I am not sure what I am saying. The slope seems fine, but the pipes don't seem to be evacuating the water fast enough. Plumber says it's par for the course for a slimline tray, but that if we switch do a deeper trap we may improve things slightly.

Comment: A quick google search yields this [brief explanation of slimline shower trays](http://www.bathroomtrade.co.uk/shower-tray-buying-guide.html) which mentions something about a "turbo shower waste" being necessary, which I'm assuming is a pump-augmented drain, or just a better drain design.